# CodeDom add reference to existing file

Tags: c#, reference, codedom

In visual studio, I can click on "Reference" > "Add reference" and browse to an existing .dll file from my computer. I can then use the referenced dll as follows:

```
dllNameSpace.dllClassName myReference = new dllNameSpace.dllClassName();
myReference.someVoid();
```

I know how to add a referenced assembly using codedom (will show this below), but the actual dll file is not being added to the project as it is when done through Visual Studio. Again, I need to be able to call some function in the dll file I'd like to reference.

**What I'm doing now:**

```
            // Configure a CompilerParameters that links the system.dll and produces the specified executable file.
            string[] referenceAssemblies = { 
                                            "System.dll", 
                                            "System.Drawing.dll", 
                                            "System.Windows.Forms.dll", 
                                            "System.Data.dll",
                                            "System.Xml.dll",
                                            "System.Management.dll",
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + @"\myDllFile.dll"
                                           };

            CompilerParameters cp = new CompilerParameters(referenceAssemblies, exeFile, false);
```

I'm assuming that I will need to do something *different* in order to have CodeDom add the dll to the output executable file. What more needs to be done here?

Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: This works fine in Visual Studio, I'm trying to get the same effect using Codedom.

Comment: Is there a compile function or method that you must Invoke once you use that.. I know that CompilerParameters has 4 overloads and what you are doing looks correct.. but when are you actually creating the dll ? looks like your just adding it to cp via the referenceAssemblies string array  this MSDN Site will also help server as a Reference aside from @Manas great example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.compilerparameters.aspx

Comment: The dll file already exists prior to my CodeDom code running.

Comment: I did it the same way you did it, and it worked like a charm for me, it is just like add it in the IDE, i was able to use the functions inside the `dll` file!!!

Answer (score 0):

Following code may help you in loading the assembly and invoke method.

```
        Assembly asmbly = Assembly.LoadFile("assembly.test.dll");
        var myclass = asmbly.GetType("MyClass"); // use FullName i.e. Namespace.Classname
        var myobj = Activator.CreateInstance(myclass);
        myclass.GetMethod("MyMethod").Invoke(myobj,new object[]{"param1","param2"});
```

Comment: Yes, I understand how to load and invoke - I do not want to do this though. In Visual Studio I can simply reference a dll and call it. Why can't I have this same functionality using CodeDom?